# Computing $(1+\cos \alpha +i\sin \alpha )^{100}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How to prove that

$$ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎(1+‎\cos ‎‎\alpha ‎+i‎\sin ‎‎\alpha ‎)^{100} =‎ ‎2^{100}‎\left( ‎‎\cos \left(‎\frac{‎\alpha‎}{2}\right)‎\right) ‎^{100} ‎‎\left( ‎‎\cos \left(‎\frac{100‎\alpha‎}{2}\right)+i‎\sin   \left(‎\frac{100‎\alpha‎}{2}\right)‎\right)‎‎$$

I just need a hint. I tried to write $1+‎\cos ‎‎\alpha ‎+i‎\sin ‎‎\alpha$ in polar form and use De,Moivre theorem. But it was impossible to compute $\arctan \frac{\sin \alpha}{1+\cos \alpha}$.

Answer (score 12):

$$1+\cos\alpha+i\sin \alpha=1+e^{i\alpha}=e^{\frac{i\alpha}{2}}(e^{-\frac{i\alpha}{2}}+e^{\frac{i\alpha}{2}})=2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)e^{\frac{i\alpha}{2}}$$

Comment: So beautiful solution

Answer (score 5):

Hint: By double-angle formulas for sine and cosine, we have $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}=\frac{2\sin(\alpha/2)\cos(\alpha/2)}{2\cos^2(\alpha/2)}.$$

Comment: Oh , yes. That completely solves my problem.

Comment: The solution suggested by mathcounterexamples.net is nicer.

Answer (score 3):

The figure below should make it easy to simplify the expression
$\arctan \dfrac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}$.
Note the isoceles triangle; you are looking for the angle at vertex $A$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a good view.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& (1+\cos \alpha+i \sin \alpha)^{100} \\
= & \left(2 \cos ^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}+2 i \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} \cos \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^{100} \\
= & {\left[2 \cos \frac{\alpha}{2}\left(\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}+i \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right]^{100} } \\
= & 2^{100} \cos ^{100} \frac{\alpha}{2}(\cos 50 \alpha+i \sin 50 \alpha)
\end{aligned}
$$